# Using return and short-hand if in C#

Tags: c#, syntax

Why wouldn't the following line of code work in a method?

```
return (count > 0) ? true : false;
```

It works perfectly fine if I do:

```
bool ret = (count > 0) ? true : false;
return ret;
```

**Bonus Question**: Is it really faster or more effective than the standard if statement?

```
bool ret = false;
if(count > 0)
    ret = true;
return ret;
```

Which one would you recommend?

Comment: I take it that there's no compile time error, just that the method returns the wrong value?

Comment: It was a compile time error... There was an error in my syntax.

Comment: what frequently happens in the case of the tertiary operator is that the evaluation of the first result (count > 0) determines the return value that the function will use.  I assume that your function returns bool?<br>
I would try to ascertain the value of the (count > 0).  If that's the issue, you may have to case the entire statement:<br>
return (bool)((count > 0) ? true : false);
it's an oddity I've see in other places.

Comment: also, bonus question, they should compile to exactly the same (as would the 3rd variation:
<code>
bool ret;
if (count > 0)
{
   ret = true;
}
else 
{
   ret = false
}

return ret;
</code>


But, I've always thought that the tertiary operator showed a more complete grok of the 'C' language :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
return count > 0;
```

There's no need to explicitly return `true` or `false`.

Having said that, your compilation error intrigues me. At first sight it looks like it should work. Could you post a short but complete example that fails to compile? The type of that conditional expression should be `bool` with no problems. My guess is you've got a more complicated scenario, and by simplifying the example you've removed the real problem.

As for the bonus question: I don't know which would be faster, nor do I care in 99.99% of cases. I'd be *amazed* to find that it caused any significant delay, unless it prohibited inlining for some reason. Go for the most *readable* solution - which is the simple return statement, IMO.

Comment: Thanks Jon, the problem was a simple syntax error that went unnoticed (usually until AFTER you ask what's wrong on SO). I like this answer, it's even shorter! return count > 0;

Answer (score 12):

try this:

```
return count > 0;
```

before return returns the expression count > 0 is evaluated and gives true or false.

this should also work:

```
return (count > 0 ? true : false);
```

but I'd recommend you didn't do this.

I always try to keep the amount of horizontal operations low, I believe it makes it easier to read code.

just imagine the following scenario which will just confuse :)

```
return count > 0 ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 5):

From the point of view of C#

```
return count > 0;
```

is better for it's readabilty.

But the compiler optmize the code, so your three options are actually the same once compiled. You could try to look at the IL code to verify!

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
return (count > 0 ? true : false);
```

You can then make it return other values than true and false.  In your particular case I would do like the other suggestions; return count > 0;